# Choosing which element to keep when intersecting python sets with custom objects

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, set, intersection

Suppose I have an object called `Node`

`Node` has two properties, `name` and `age`

I have a set of `Nodes` called `set1` and another called `set2`

I want to get the intersection of `set1` and `set2`.

However I want the comparisons within the intersection method to be purely based on the `name` property.

This is done by overriding the `__eq__` method.

This means if `Node("Jenna", 54)` existed in `set1` and `Node("Jenna", 29)` existed in `set2` then one of those `Nodes` will exist in the instersection.

How do I force the intersection to keep the `Node` from `set1` if it exists in the intersection with `set2`.

I.e - in the above example, how do I force the intersection to contain `Node("Jenna", 54)` and **NOT** `Node("Jenna", 29)` ?

Any ideas?

Comment: Later sets will always replace items in earlier sets, I think, so you could order the intersection on that basis (i.e. `set2.intersection(set1)`). But it seems like you aren't really using sets semantically if you care which element is in the output.

Comment: I've tried reversing the order of the operation.. it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [What's the algorithm of 'set.intersection()' in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100003/whats-the-algorithm-of-set-intersection-in-python)

If you override `__eq__` and `__hash__` it could work, but intersection will keep elements of the shortest set.

Another way to do that is this:

```
s2_names = {n.name for n in s2}
inter = {n for n in s1 if s1.name in s2_names}
```