# How to put symbols into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I put symbols such as \, /, :, *, ?, ", <, >, | into a list?

if I do this:

```
illegalchar = ['\', '/' ,':' ,'*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
```

the commas separating the items will be counted as a string including the `]`

PS: It is to check if the filename contains illegal characters (can't be made into a file), so if there's any alternative methods, please do tell me, thanks!

Comment: Try `['\\', '/', ...`

Comment: You do not need a list for this. A string is more compact: `illegalchar = ['\\/:*?"<>|']`. But you still have to escape the backslash,

Comment: @KlausD. Is \\  the same as \? i've heard it somewhere but i've forgotten, i want to double confirm, thanks anyway!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a good old regex via the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) module?

Comment: @pstatix sorry, i haven't learned about regex, still quite new to python

Comment: @DyZ so does it still work when using `illegalchar not in x`?

Comment: The backslash is an escape character. It creates escape sequences together with the following character(s). In your case it made the quotation mark not to terminate the string. A double backslash on the other hand is the escape sequence for a single backslash.

Comment: @JeffNg regular expressions are a fundamental concept in computer languages. Read through the module I have given you!

Comment: thanks guys! you all have been helpful

Comment: No it does not. You must check each character individually in a loop.

Comment: You can remove the brackets, make it a string, and do `x not in '\\/:*?"<>|'`, which is faster and more readable than a python loop

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai You still have to loop through each `x` in the file name. The real no-loop solution is to do set intersection: `set(filename) & set('\\/:*?"<>|') == set()`

Comment: @DyZ "You still have to loop through each x in the file name": Incorrect, you only have to loop to the first x in the file name that is an illegal character. "The real no-loop solution is to do set intersection": Also incorrect. It still loops as explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100003/whats-the-algorithm-of-set-intersection-in-python

Comment: @NoticeMeSenpai By "no-loop solutions" we usually mean no-python-loop solutions. If a loop is implements in C (as I hope is the case with the & operator), its performance is not an issue. It's a `for` loop that should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use raw strings (denoted by putting an `r` in front of your strings).  Then, transform your raw string into list:

```
illegals = [i for i in r'\/:*?"<>|']

# OR, using @abccd's suggestion, just use list()

illegals = list(r'\/:*?"<>|')

illegals
# ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
```

Note the `'\\'` when printed is still a single backslash, but in value the first backslash is stored as an escape character.

You can read more on the [documentation of lexical analysis.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

This answers the question, but in reality you a `string` is treated like a `list` of characters, so both of the following will return the same elements:

```
[i for i in list(r'\/:*?"<>|')]
[c for c in  r'\/:*?"<>|']
```

As for how to identify if a filename has any of these characters, you can do this:

```
valid_file = 'valid_script.py'
invalid_file = 'invalid?script.py'

validate = lambda f: not any(c for c in r'\/:*?"<>|' if c in f)

validate(valid_file)
# True

validate(invalid_file)
# False
```

This is just one of the many ways.  You might even opt for a regex approach:

```
import re

# Note in regex you still need to escape the slash and backslash in the match group
validate = lambda f: not re.search(r'[\\\/:*?\"<>|]+', f)

validate(valid_file)
# True

validate(invalid_file)
# False
```

Comment: What's the point of `[i for i in r'\/:*?"<>|']`? You can do `list(r'\/:*?"<>|')` to the same effect, but even this is not needed.

Comment: @DyZ I realized after the fact `list()` will do just fine.  While I know you can just interpret the string as a list of individual char, OP specially asks how to put them in a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters like `\` in the string before inserting them into the array, like this:

```
In [2]: something = ["\\", "/"]
In [3]: something
Out[3]: ['\\', '\/']
```

Printing it will give you the escaped backslash

```
In [12]: something = ["\\", "/"]
In [13]: something
Out[13]: ['\\', '/']
In [14]: print ', '.join(something)
\, /
```

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is just to check for illegal characters, you are doing an overkill here with complex stuffs. python `string` allow for lookup as they are iterators too. I would go with below easy approach :

```
In [5]: illegalchar = '\/:*?"<>|'

In [6]: if "/" in illegalchar:
            print("nay")
   ...:
nay
```

downside : one type of `quote`s have to be skipped which *surround* the string (`'` in this case)

Comment: One type of quotes doesn't have to be missed. You can escape the char of the surround quotes by adding a backslash. It'd look like this: `\'`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the escape character `\` before the backslash `\`.

Change

```
illegalchar = ['\', '/' ,':' ,'*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
```

to

```
illegalchar = ['\\', '/' ,':' ,'*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
```