# Is there a brief way to Get the indices of all elements from list A in list B

Tags: python, list, indexing

Assume we have two lists, A and B. Is there a way to get the indices of elements in the list B, which are in the list A?

For example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [3,4,1,2,5]
```

The result should be:

```
[2,3,0,1]
```

Could it be implemented without for-loop (or fast)?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to get the indices. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find indexes of common items in two python lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171314/find-indexes-of-common-items-in-two-python-lists)

Comment: `[B.index(a) for a in A]`

Comment: Do read @MadyDaby's link.  You can't do it without `for` loops, but you have the `for` loop be part of a list comprehension.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: actually i meet this problem when using pytorch:) i hope to get some inspiration from python. What i did is `[(i == B).nonzero() for i in A]`

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your use case:

```py
result = [A.index(x) for x in B if x in A]
```

Comment: thx, i see for-loop is necessary:)

Answer (score 0):

Use index function

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [3,4,1,2,5]
lst=[]
for i in A:
    res=B.index(i)
    lst.append(res)
print(lst)
# [2, 3, 0, 1]
```

Comment: yes with for loop it is easy