# How do I split a set into two sets by intersection with another set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, set

Let's say I have two sets:

```py
s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
s2 = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

I want to split `s1` into `{4, 5}` and `{1, 2, 3}`, where the first part is an intersection of `s1` and `s2`, and the second part is the remainder.

I can do it like this:

```py
part1 = s1.intersection(s2)
part2 = s1.difference(s2)
```

But it seems to me that this way I'll perform quite the same operation twice, which can take a long while on big sets. Can I do it with one operation in Python? I want to do something like

```py
part1, part2 = slit_sets(s1, s2)
```

Comment: inters=s1.intersection(s2)
part1,part2 = inters, s1-inters

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Will you expect to split the set for many times?

Comment: @jasonwong the service will split different sets many times, yes, so I try to find the quickest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single builtin operation which will return both the intersection *and* the difference, so you will always need to call two methods.

Intuitively I expected

```
i = s1.intersection(s2)
d = s1.difference(i)
return i,d
```

to be faster than

```
i = s1.intersection(s2)
d = s1.difference(s2)
return i,d
```

since it calculates the difference against a smaller set, but this is untrue - `timeit` results are roughly equivalent even for large sets with some thousands elements in them. A slight improvement, around 5%, is achieved instead with

```
d = s1.difference(s2)
i = s1.difference(d)
return i,d
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use simple loop:

```
def slit_sets(s1, s2):
    inter = set()
    diff = set()
    for s in s1:
        if s in s2:
            inter.add(s)
        else:
            diff.add(s)
    return inter, diff
```

Comment: I used `timeit` to measure that `[el for el in s2 if el in s1]` takes at least twice longer than `s1.intersection(s2)`, which is why I want to avoid loops

Comment: that's interesting. i'm not familiar with internal implementaions. but searched and found the implementiation is similiar loop: [What's the algorithm of 'set.intersection()' in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100003/whats-the-algorithm-of-set-intersection-in-python)

Comment: perhaps it's because `intersection` is performed in `C` while the loop is just Python?

Comment: i think so. the big O complexity is the same. so I think they made not that big difference.